# Graph theory: how do you visualize a random walk when the underlying graph has cycles?

Tags: graph-theory

I am not asking for code. My conceptual knowledge is a bit limited, I may not even use the right term (e.g. maybe I'm not talking about a walk).

The context that I use these graphs in are story line choices.

In any case, suppose I have the following directed graph (the colors are arbitrary):
[image: Non-cyclical directed graph]

Then a visualization of the walk (at alpha == 1) including a visualization of the rest of the complete graph (at alpha == 0.25) looks as follows:
[image: Walk visualization of non-cyclical directed graph]

This visualization shows:

- the underlying topology
- which node was visited first
- which nodes were visited

My issue is that this type of visualization would not work for cyclical graphs, since there is no way of knowing how many times a user has visited that node if you would lay it out like this.

Here is a visual example
[image: cyclical directed graph]

Here is a possible visual representation, where the user walks forth and back once on the cycle
[image: Walk visualization of cyclical directed graph]

As you can see, there is no way of visualizing (in this style) that the user walked the cycle (fully or partially) 2 times, 3 times or maybe even a 100 times (assuming that every node is also a terminating point).

My question is: what are possible visualization methods that show:

- which node was visited first
- which nodes were visited

And if there is no real objective answer to that, what terms could I use to Google for it for inspiration? Things like: graph theory walk visualization or graph theory random walk visualization didn't yield fruitful results.

Comment: If you are interested in the properties of nodes, you should use the node markers to visualise those. E.g. you could use size to represent the frequency with which a node was visited and a color gradient to show the average path length before the first visit of said node.